# AsyncHttpClient post and get JSON response

Tags: java, android, json, asynchttpclient

I have to post a JSON to server and the server retrieves me another. I tried this but it doesn't work. When I debug, I never see the logs in on Success or onFailure:

```
       String url = "https://*******/sessions";


        JSONObject requestObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            requestObject.put("company", "TEST");
            requestObject.put("user", "*****");
            requestObject.put("secure_password", "8ce241e1ed84937ee48322b170b9b18c2");
            requestObject.put("secure_device_id", "C4CA4238A0B923820DCC509A6F75849B");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


//        JSONObject jsonParams = new JSONObject();
//        jsonParams.put("notes", "Test api support");
        StringEntity entity = null;
        try {
            entity = new StringEntity(requestObject.toString());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        entity.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
        client.post(this, url, entity, "application/json",
                new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                        String res = responseBody.toString();
                        Log.e("response " , res);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

                    }
                });
```

How I can get the response body?

Comment: You should tell us what you get now. I can see that you do it wrong indeed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand clearly what you are asking, but you will never see the response because you **can't convert** the `reponseBody` to String like `String res = responseBody.toString();` .

**Do** `String res = new String(responseBody);` **instead.**

If that's not the problem update your question and I'll update my answer.